# Pycord CogMeta class doesn't exist

Tags: python, pycord

I wanted to make a custom Cog class with the CogMeta supposingly existing in [`discord.ext.commands`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#cogmeta), but when I do `discord.ext.commands.CogMeta` it error `AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'CogMeta'`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking the docs linked in the question, looking at version `master`, the CogMeta class is `discord.cog.CogMeta`, as opposed to on version `stable`, where it is `discord.ext.commands.CogMeta` as you assumed.  So probably you are using the `master` version rather than the `stable` version.

Link to master version: https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/ext/commands/api.html#cogmeta
Link to stable version: https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#cogmeta

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what happened